# spark creating num of partitions in RDD more than the data size

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am a noob and learning Pyspark now. My question about RDD is what happens when we try to create more partitions than the data size. E.g.,

```
data = sc.parallelize(range(5), partitions = 8)
```

I understand the intention of partitions is to effectively use the CPU cores of a cluster, and making too small partitions involves scheduling overhead than benefitting from distributed computing. What I am curious about is does spark still create 8 partitions here or optimize it to the number of cores? If it's creating 8 partitions then there is data replication in each partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question about RDD is what happens when we try to create more
> partitions than the data size

You can easily see how many partitions a given RDD has by using
`data.getNumPartitions`. I tried creating RDD you have mentioned and running this command and it shows me there are 8 partitions. 4 partitions had one number each and rest 4 empty.

> If it's creating 8 partitions then there is data replication in each
> partition?

You can try following code and check the executor output to see how many records are there in each partition. Note the first print statement in the below code. I have to return something as required by API so returning each element multiplied by 2.

```
data.mapPartitionsWithIndex((x,y) => {println(s"partitions $x has ${y.length} records");y.map(a => a*2)}).collect.foreach(println)
```

I got following output for the above code -

```
partitions 0 has 0 records
partitions 1 has 1 records
partitions 2 has 0 records
partitions 3 has 1 records
partitions 4 has 0 records
partitions 5 has 1 records
partitions 6 has 0 records
partitions 7 has 1 records
```

> I am curious about is does spark still create 8 partitions here or
> optimize it to the number of cores?

Number of partitions defines how much data you want spark to process in one task. If there are 8 partitions and 4 virtual cores then spark would start running 4 tasks ( corresponding to 4 partitions) at once. As these tasks finishes, it will schedule remaining ones those cores.

Comment: Thanks, Amit. So the application continues executing the same transformations on both empty and non-empty partitions also.

Comment: for empty partitions it has nothing do so nothing would be done there.